# Bad (unattractive) blending in OpenGL with bright figures on dark background

Tags: c, opengl, textures, blending

I have a problems in OpenGL with blending (in result of antialiasing or textured painting). See problem illustration:

[image: Problem illustration]

I have the following setup code

```
// Antialiasing
glEnable(GL_POINT_SMOOTH);
glEnable(GL_LINE_SMOOTH);
// Blending
glBlendFunc(GL_SRC_ALPHA, GL_ONE_MINUS_SRC_ALPHA);
glEnable(GL_BLEND);
// Texture font
glTexParameterf(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER, GL_NEAREST);
glTexParameterf(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER, GL_NEAREST);
glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_S, GL_CLAMP);
glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_T, GL_CLAMP);
```

Please, point me to the solution of this problem.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

OpenGL blends in a linear RGB color space, but your monitor is not linear.  This causes the apparent alpha to change depending on whether the background is light or dark.  Try using the `GL_EXT_framebuffer_sRGB` extension.

Comment: Works great, thanks a lot! The only thing is that I've used GL_ARB_framebuffer_sRGB, which seems to be identical, but more recent (2008 against 2006).