# sRGB FBO render to texture

Tags: opengl, srgb

In my renderer, I produce an anti-aliased scene on a multisampled FBO, which is blitted to an FBO whose color attachment is a texture. The texture is then read during rendering to the framebuffer.

I'd like to update it so that I get gamma-correct results. The benefit of using an sRGB framebuffer is that it allows me to have a somewhat better color precision by storing nonlinear sRGB values directly in the framebuffer.

What I'm not sure about is what changes should I be making to get this, and what is being changed by the different settings.

It looks like [extension ARB_framebuffer_sRGB](http://www.opengl.org/registry/specs/ARB/framebuffer_sRGB.txt) is just dealing with reading and blending operations with sRGB framebuffers. In my situation I'll need to use a texture specifying a sRGB representation type, which means I'd be using extension [EXT_texture_sRGB](http://www.opengl.org/registry/specs/EXT/texture_sRGB.txt)... using a linear texture format would disable the sRGB translation.

Edit: But I just saw this:

> 3)  Should the ability to support sRGB framebuffer update and blending
>      be an attribute of the framebuffer?
>
> RESOLVED:  Yes.  It should be a capability of some pixel formats
>      (mostly likely just RGB8 and RGBA8) that says sRGB blending can
>      be enabled.
>
> This allows an implementation to simply mark the existing RGB8
>      and RGBA8 pixel formats as supporting sRGB blending and then
>      just provide the functionality for sRGB update and blending for
>      such formats.

Now I'm not so sure what to specify for my texture's pixel format.

Okay, and what about renderbuffers? the ARB_framebuffer_sRGB doc does not mention anything about renderbuffers. Is it possible to use `glRenderbufferStorageMultisample` with a sRGB format, so I can get sRGB storage enabled blending?

Also, what is the difference between `GL_SRGB_ALPHA` and `GL_SRGB8_ALPHA8` when specifying the internal format for [`glTexImage2D`](http://www.opengl.org/sdk/docs/man3/xhtml/glTexImage2D.xml)?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

> What I'm not sure about is what changes should I be making to get this

That's because your question seems unsure about what you're trying to do.

The key to all of this stuff is to at all times know what your input data is and what your output data is.

Your first step is to know what is stored in each of your textures. Does a particular texture store linear data or data in the sRGB colorspace? If it stores linear data, then use one of the linear image formats. If it stores sRGB colorspace data, then use one of the sRGB image formats.

This ensures that you are fetching the data you want in your shaders. When it comes time to write/blend them to the framebuffer, you now need to decide how to handle that.

Your screen expects values that have been pre-gamma corrected to the gamma of the display device. As such, if you provide linear values, you will get incorrect color output.

However, sometimes, you want to write to intermediate values. For example, if you're doing forward or deferred rendering, you will write accumulated lighting to a floating-point buffer, then use HDR tone mapping to boil it down to a [0, 1] image for display. Post-processing techniques can again be used. Only the outputs to [0, 1] need to be to images in the sRGB colorspace.

When writing linear RGB values that you want converted into sRGB, you must enable `GL_FRAMEBUFFER_SRGB`. This is a special enable (note that textures don't have a way to turn off sRGB decoding) because sometimes, you want to write values that already are in sRGB. This is often the case for GUI interface widgets, which were designed and built using colors already in the sRGB colorspace.

I cover issues relating to [writing gamma-correct values](https://nicolbolas.github.io/oldtut/Illumination/Tut12%20Monitors%20and%20Gamma.html) and [reading them from textures](https://nicolbolas.github.io/oldtut/Texturing/Tutorial%2016.html) in my tutorial series. The first one explains why gamma is important and does explicitly gamma correction in the shader. The second link covers how to use sRGB images, both in textures and framebuffers.

> Okay, and what about renderbuffers? the ARB_framebuffer_sRGB doc does not mention anything about renderbuffers.

And why would it? ARB_framebuffer_sRGB is only interested in the framebuffer and the nature of images in it. It neither knows nor cares where those images come from. It doesn't care if it's talking about the default framebuffer, a texture attached to an FBO, a renderbuffer attached to an FBO, or something entirely new someone comes up with tomorrow.

The extension states what happens when the destination image is in the sRGB colorspace and when `GL_FRAMEBUFFER_SRGB` is enabled. Where that image comes from is up to you.

> Also, what is the difference between GL_SRGB_ALPHA and GL_SRGB8_ALPHA8 when specifying the internal format for glTexImage2D?

One is sized. The other is not. In theory, `GL_SRGB_ALPHA` could give you any bitdepth the implementation wanted. It could give you 2 bits per component. You're giving the implementation freedom to pick what it wants.

In practice, I doubt you'll find a difference. That being said, *always* used sized internal formats whenever possible. It's good to be specific about what you want, and to prevent the implementation from doing something stupid. OpenGL even has some sized formats which are [required to be supported explicitly as stated](http://www.opengl.org/wiki/Image_Format#Required_formats).

Comment: I'd like to add, that you should stay in linear color space for as much as possible.

Comment: Can I think of `GL_FRAMEBUFFER_SRGB` as a toggle? It determines whether translation (sRGB->linear during read; linear->sRGB during write) is performed. In my case, I am writing linear values to my intermediate FBO so I should be using a regular texture.

Comment: @StevenLu: A toggle? It doesn't "toggle" anything; it's either enabled or its not. It's called GL_**FRAMEBUFFER**_SRGB because it deals with *writes*. To the framebuffer. You're really thinking of this the wrong way. Data is either linear or sRGB. The holder of that data (ie: image) therefore either thinks it is linear or thinks it's sRGB. Everything you read from a texture is *linear*. Everything you write is *linear*. If you're writing to an sRGB image when `GL_FRAMEBUFFER_SRGB` is enabled, then it will take that linear value and convert it to sRGB.

Comment: Okay. What happens if I draw to a buffer, THEN `glEnable(GL_FRAMEBUFFER_SRGB)`, then read from it? I will be reading the linearized value (so it will be darker than my input), yes? If `GL_FRAMEBUFFER_SRGB` is enabled (on a proper 8bit format) then it will treat the stored data as sRGB values and perform translation on operations. If it is disabled, it will treat the stored data as linear values and no translation is performed as long as it is disabled.

Comment: @StevenLu: You are really overthinking this. An image that stores sRGB data stores *sRGB data*. Therefore, when you write to it, what you are writing is either itself sRGB or is linear. If you write data without `GL_FRAMEBUFFER_SRGB`, then you are saying that the values you are writing *are* sRGB values. If you write data with it enabled, then you are saying that the values are linear and need to be converted to sRGB. Texture accesses always yield linear colorspace values, regardless of what they're accessing.

Comment: @NicolBolas Okay. I'm trying to specify my colors in sRGB but blend/process them linearly (for antialiasing and blur). This would mean I disable it during color fetching and drawing, then enable during post processing (linear operations using the sRGB encoded framebuffer data), and re-disable after finishing the frame.

Comment: Is it not true that the linear values I read out of a texture will depend on whether I've indicated said texture to be containing sRGB or linear values? the former of which will invoke a translation.

Comment: @StevenLu: Again, you're thinking about this the wrong way. Your data either is sRGB or isn't. If you have an image who's colors are in the sRGB colorspace, then the way to indicate that to OpenGL is to give it an sRGB image format. If an image's colors are not in the sRGB colorspace, the way to indicate that is to *not* give it an sRGB image format. `GL_FRAMEBUFFER_SRGB` only affects *writes* to a image that has an sRGB image format. The only reason it exists is to be able to allow you to directly write untranslated sRGB data to an sRGB image.

Comment: @NicolBolas Okay. I'm using sRGB buffers now for both the multisampled FBO and the destination texture FBO but I cannot get a gamma-correct resolve. Something did work though because my motion blur is correctly gamma-corrected now, meaning the texture FBO is being translated when it is being read. This question is talking about the same issue. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9049687/using-srgb-colour-in-qglframebufferobject-with-multisampling

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/8245/discussion-between-steven-lu-and-nicol-bolas)

Comment: Nicol, if your tutorials are still around, you might want to update the links to them in this answer.